# Issue with Wikipedia API search

Tags: parsing, search, wikipedia-api

I will getting data from Wikipedia using API.
Search string is 'STB'

**Case 1**. using API

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&list=search&srsearch=STB
```

**Case 2.** in browser: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STB

I think case 1 result is same with case 2, but it's different. How to getting result like case 2 using API?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the links from the [STB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STB) Wikipedia page you have to use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Blinks) API:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&pllimit=500&plnamespace=0&titles=STB
```